# 【Angular2】setIntervalでコンポーネントの値変更チェックを行わない方法

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

画面のオートスクロール機能を作っているのですが、setIntervalで値変更チェックが行われる為、とても重くなってしまいます。
オートスクロールではコンポーネントの値などが変わる事はないので、変更チェックは不要です。
変更チェックを行わないsetInterval関数はないですか？

Answer (score 1):

`NgZone`クラスの`runOutsideAngular`メソッドを使って解決できるはずです。コンポーネントのDependency Injectionで`NgZone`のインスタンスを取得してから利用します。

サンプル

```
export class SomeCmp {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {})
    });
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#runOutsideAngular-anchor

Comment: ありがとうございます。NgZoneという名前は聞いた事ありましたが、何に使うかよく分かっていませんでした。他にも色々メソッドがあったので調べたら応用出来そうです。